# Toggle text on button tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a show hide table rows feature but would now like to change my text.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function HideStuff(thisname) {
    tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');        
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if (tr[i].getAttribute('classname') == 'display:none;') {
            if (tr[i].style.display == 'none' || tr[i].style.display=='block' )  {
                tr[i].style.display = ''; 
            }
            else {
                tr[i].style.display = 'block'; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The html is as follows...

```
<button id="ShowHide" onclick="HideStuff('hide');>Show/Hide</button>
```

I want to toggle the "Show/Hide" text.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery something like this might work:

```
$('ShowHide').click(function(){
    if ( $('hide').css('display') == 'block' )
        $('ShowHide').val("Hide");
    else
        $('ShowHide').val("Show");
});
```

I just wrote that from the top of my head though, so you might need to do some changes, you can read more about the [css jquery api here](http://api.jquery.com/css/). And all I did was using anonymous functions

Comment: He is asking about how to change the text inside the button tag.

Comment: And how hard would it be to change my answer then? I just missread.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think of editing it for you. Anyway, downvote taken back.

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#HideShow').click(function() 
{ 
  if ($(this).text() == "Show") 
  { 
     $(this).text("Hide"); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
     $(this).text("Show"); 
  }; 
});
```

Alternative, the .toggle() has an .toggle(even,odd); functionality, use which ever makes most sense to you, one is slightly shorter code but perhaps less definitive.

```
$('#HideShow').toggle(function()  
  {  
   $(this).text("Hide");  
     HideClick('hide');
  },  
  function()  
  {  
     $(this).text("Show"); 
     HideClick('hide'); 
  }  
);
```

NOTE: you can include any other actions you want in the function() as needed, and you can eliminate the onclick in the markup/html by calling your HideClick() function call in there. as I demonstrate in the second example.

As a follow-up, and to present an alternative, you could add CSS class to your CSS

```
.hideStuff
{
display:none;
}
```

THEN add this in:

```
.toggle('.hideStuff');
```

or, more directly:in the appropriate place.

```
.addClass('.hideStuff');
.removeClass('.hideStuff');
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using jquery but you can just use javascript's `document.getElementById` method

in your function:

```
function HideStuff(thisname) {
    tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        if (tr[i].getAttribute('classname') == 'display:none;') {
            if (tr[i].style.display == 'none' || tr[i].style.display == 'block') {
                tr[i].style.display = 'none';

            }
            else {
                tr[i].style.display = 'block';

            }
        }
    }
    if (document.getElementById("ShowHide").value == "show") {
        document.getElementById("ShowHide").value = "hide";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("ShowHide").value = "show";
    }

}
```

Although, I would probably pass in `this` instead of the text 'hide' in the function call. then yon can do it like zaph0d stated. Its a bit cleaner then.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are passing thisname into the JS as this is not currently getting used.

If you change the call to:

```
<button id="ShowHide" onclick="HideStuff(this)">Show</button>
```

and then in the js you can change the text fairly easily:

```
if (this.value == 'Show') {
  this.value = 'Hide'
}
else {
  this.value = 'Show';
}
```